# Can I have "." as part of column name in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For example, I have following code `create table if not exists table_name (lease no. varchar(255))`
It shows

> unexpected 'no'.

,
Is there a way that I can have dot in column name in snowflake?

Comment: Please accept the correct answer from @teha - yes you can have this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only alphanum and underscore (_) as separator. Not dots allowed. But if you scape them as @Teja Goud Kandula suggest you could acchieve it with that hack.

Comment: See the answer from @Teja - you can have dots in the column name (if you escape the name)

Answer (score 2):

```
create or replace table test1 (
    "lease no." varchar(255)
)
;

insert into test1 ("lease no.")
values ('random text1') ;

select "lease no." from test1 ;
```

[image]

It is possible but the column name needs to be wrapped up in double quotes.
When accessing the column the double quotes should be used.